# How to pass Scenario name from the Cucumber feature file as a parameter in the Cucumber steps?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I need some help, would appreciate if someone can help?

I need pass the Scenario Name in the Cucumber feature file as a parameter in the steps..

In the Background step- I am launching the browser and logging in to the application, so that I do not have to repeat the same steps in every scenario. There is a JAVA method to start the video recording for the GUI which is being used in the Background test- and the video recording will be there for individual scenarios- So if there are 10 scenarios in the feature file- the video recording needs to give 10 outputs which shows the automation run for these 10 scenarios. The method for video recording capture saves the file name based on the argument which will be passed.

For example- My Scenario in the Feature file is:

```
Feature: Do Something

Background:
    Given I start the recording for the scenario "Pass the scenario name here"
    And I navigate to the login page
    When I submit username and password
    Then I should be logged in 

Scenario: Scenario Name
    Given I start the test for "Scenario Name"
    Then it should do something
    And stop the recording

Scenario: Scenario Name 2
    Given I start the test for "Scenario Name 2"
    Then it should do something
    And stop the recording
```

How can i pass the Scenario name as a parameter in the Step?

Comment: What language are you writing step definitions in?

Comment: Step Definition code is in JAVA

Comment: In the Background: I want to pass the Scenarios name as a parameter- my step in background is- Given i start the recording for "This is where i want to pass the scenario name as a parameter" ... In the respective scenarios- I want to add the last step as- And i stop the recording for "This is where again i want to pass the name of the scenario"... The argument is the scenario name which should be used by the two methods.. Does it make sense now?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not how cucumber was meant to be used. There is a philosophy behind it. I highly recomment reading [BDD 101: Introducing BDD](https://automationpanda.com/2017/01/25/bdd-101-introducing-bdd/) and [Writing Good Gherkin](https://automationpanda.com/2017/01/30/bdd-101-writing-good-gherkin/).

Comment: In the Background: I want to pass the Scenarios name as a parameter- my step in background is- Given i start the recording for "This is where i want to pass the scenario name as a parameter" ... In the respective scenarios- I want to add the last step as- And i stop the recording for "This is where again i want to pass the name of the scenario"... The argument is the scenario name which should be used by the two methods.. Does it make sense now?

Comment: It makes sense. I'm saying that this is not the way you should be doing it. Each scenario needs the proper `Given` steps to set things up. What do you mean by "start recording"? Maybe this is where I'm getting confused.

Comment: In the Background step- I am launching the browser and loging in to the application, so that I do not have to repeat the same steps in every scenario. There is a JAVA method to start the video recording for the GUI which is under test- and the video recording will be there for individual scenarios- So if there are 10 scenarios in the feature file- the video recording needs to give 10 outputs which shows the automation run for these 10 scenarios. The method for video recording capture saves the file name based on the arugument which will be passed.

Comment: And in this case the argument needs to be the name of the scenario- so that the file gets saved with the scenario name

Comment: Ah, ok. This is vital information. Please add this to your question.

Comment: Thanks Greg, please let me know if there is any solution to this, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Starting a recording of the test execution is not something that belongs in your cucumber test. And as you have found, it is very difficult to accomplish what you want.

This is where [Cucumber Hooks](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#hooks) can help:

```
@Binding
public class TestRecorder {
    private final VideoRecorder videoRecorder;

    public TestRecorder() {
        this(new VideoRecorder(...));
    }

    public TestRecorder(VideoRecorder videoRecorder) {
        this.videoRecorder = videoRecorder;
    }

    @Before
    public void BeginRecording(Scenario scenario) {
        String scenarioName = scenario.getName();

        // do something with scenarioName and start recording...
        videoRecorder.start();
    }

    @After
    public void StopRecording(Scenario scenario) {
        String scenarioName = scenario.getName();

        // Stop recording, and use scenarioName to save to a file
        videoRecorder.stop();
    }
}
```

Before the scenario starts, begin the video recording. The TestRecorder class can declare private fields to hold a reference to the video recorder. The `Scenario` object passed in to the before and after scenario hooks (BeginRecording and StopRecording) give you information about the scenario, including the name. This should give you enough to save the video recording to a file using the scenario name as the file name.

And since this is just a POJO, you could write some unit tests for the video recording functionality too (if you really wanted).

Now your cucumber tests can stay focused on the system under test, and the not system monitoring the test:

```
Feature: Do Something

Background:
    Given I navigate to the login page
    When I submit username and password
    Then I should be logged in 

Scenario: Scenario Name
    When I do the thing
    Then it should do something

Scenario: Scenario Name 2
    When I do the thing
    Then it should do something
```

No need to pass the scenario name from the feature file. It's all done "behind the scenes" in the cucumber hooks.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great feedback! :)